# How do I export an enhanced component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, higher-order-functions, recompose

I have a common folder with several components and an index.js file that looks like this:

```
export * from './Alert'
export * from './Button'
...
```

I do this so I can import them like this:

```
import { Alert, Button } from './common'
```

In each of those (stateless) components, I export the component like this:

```
export { Alert }
```

I'm now creating a new component that is enhanced:

```
import { branch, renderComponent } from 'recompose'
...

const Loading = () =>
  <Spinner size='large' />

const FormNextButton = ( { onPress } ) =>
  <Button
    onPress={ onPress }
    title="Next"
  />

const enhance = branch(
  ( { loading } ) => loading,
  renderComponent( Loading )
)
```

But now I can't figure out how to export it so that I can use it in my index.js the same way as the other components. I tried this:

```
// #1
export { enhance( FormNextButton ) }
```

But it gives me a syntax error:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
```

I also tried this:

```
// #2
const ExportVal = enhance( FormNextButton )
export { ExportVal }
```

But it gives me an error when I try to reference it in another component:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Check the render method of `SomeComponent`.
```

How can I export this component similar to the way I'm exporting the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export it by name:

```js
// enhanced-button.js
export const EnhancedButton = enhance( FormNextButton )

// index.js
export * from './enhanced-button.js'
// ...

// import it in other module by name
import { EnhancedButton } from './common'
```